# When minting a new position why does one token is used up fully and the other is not?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

i am using this code to create and initialize a pool and mint a new position on it.

```
// 1 ETH (y) = 2000 USDC (x)
pool = IUniswapV3Pool(factory.createPool(address(weth), address(usdc), 500));
pool.initialize(1771595571142957166518320255467520); // current tick : 200311

// mint a new position
INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams memory params = 
            INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams(
                address(usdc),
                address(weth),
                500,
                200310,
                200320,
                2000 * 10 ** 6, // Desired amount of token0
                1 * 10 ** 18, // Desired amount of token1
                1900 * 10 ** 6, // Minimum amount of token1
                0.1 * 10 ** 18, // Minimum amount of token0
                recepient,
                block.timestamp + 33600 // Deadline 1 hour from now
            );
```

in the above code i have initialized a pool between usdc and weth for 500 bip fee (remember usdc has 6 decimals and weth has 18) i then initialize with a sqrtpricex96 that is based upon the price exchange 1 eth = 2000 usdc.

when i use this code to calculate price from sqrtpricex96 i get the correct price

```
def sqrtp_to_price(p):
  return (p/q96) ** 2

p = sqrtp_to_price(1771595571142957166518320255467520)
q = p * 1e6/1e18
print(q) // 0.0005
```

when minting a new position, i pass exactly that amount the 2000 usdc which gets used up fully but only o.1 of my 1 weth get used up, why? Is thehre a way to calculate the amounts that are going to get used up before hand as to avoid trial and error in slippage tolerance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniswap V3 positions consist of ticks with equal amount of liquidity in each tick. So if the current tick is 200312 and your are placing position between 200310 and 200320, the position will end up having roughly 80% of one token and 20% of the other token. NFT manager will try to maximize amounts of tokens getting in, but it's normal to have one of the two tokens left over.

To calculate how many tokens a position would take you could use something like this:

```
(uint256 amt0, uint256 amt1) = _amountsForLiquidity(
    sqrtRatioX96, // take it from slot0
    tickLow, // 200310
    tickHigh, // 200320
    10**18 // just some number here
);

// after you get amt0 and amt1 you could see the proportions between 
// these two tokens in a position with 10**18 liquidity that could 
// theoretically go in. Use this proportion to calculate real amounts 
// based on the funds you have at hand. 

function _amountsForLiquidity(
    uint160 sqrtRatioX96,
    int24 tickLower,
    int24 tickUpper,
    uint128 liquidity
) internal pure returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) {
    // LiquidityAmounts is a lib from Uniswap V3 periphery
    (amount0, amount1) = LiquidityAmounts.getAmountsForLiquidity(
        sqrtRatioX96,
        TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tickLower),
        TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tickUpper),
        liquidity
    );
}
```

Comment: why did you pass 10 ** 18 in place for liquidity? in case of usdc/weth pool should i pass 10 ** 12?

also how did you estimate on the basis of my ticks that the ration will be 80/20?

Comment: 10**18 is just a hypothetical number - doesn't matter what liquidity amount you use there. The goal is not to get real amounts, but to find in what proportion tokens will go into the position with boundaries set to 200310 and 200320. After you get amt0 and amt1, you can apply this knowledge to real amounts you want to put in (in your example 2000 * 10 ** 6 and 1 * 10 ** 18)

Comment: Let's call them t0 and t1. if amt0/t0 > amt1/t1, then 100% of token0 will go in and (t0/amt0)*amt1 of token1 will go in as well. And visa versa if amt0/t0 < amt1/t1

Comment: as far as 80/20, it's just a rough approximation for the example where current tick is 200312 and position spans 10 ticks (200310-200320). It would indicate that 2 ticks will be filled with one token and 8 ticks with the other. It's not precise at all because amounts of tokens in ticks further away from price are smaller and also composition inside the price tick itself could be different at any time. But it's an OK way to produce rough estimate just by looking at ticks

Comment: but thats the point, why aren't both token's being consumed? beacause the the ratio is set 1:1 i.e i usdc = 0.0005 eth and since their is noothe txn the ratio isn't disturbed and both of my tokens should be consumed fully

Comment: when i use the ticks 200300, 200320 my full eth gets used but only 1500 usdc, how to optimize ticks selection without trial and error?

Comment: This is actually a different question. The math above assumes that you set the boundaries and want to know how many tokens will go in. If you are looking for a way to ADJUST boundaries in order to deploy as many of your tokens as possible, you'll need to use different formula. You will also need to decide on one of the boundaries upfront. Then you can calculate the other boundary. Math is described here: https://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf . Specifically, see example 3.2.2. This way you'll get prices for both boundaries and then convert them into ticks

Comment: This makes more sense, thankyou